# How to match text to a defined numeric value

Tags: ms-access, survey

I have a database that has a bunch of survey data that I would like to work with. For several questions, the values are things like "Very important","Not at all likely" and I want to create a calculated field to assign a numeric value to these responses.

I don't want to replace the responses at all since I am going to have a user fill out a form to append the data set. I do want to have a calculated field that will automatically assign a numeric value to a text response.

I would just use a vlookup or an IF function in Excel to do this, but the problem is that Excel can't handle as much data as Access can. I need to set it up so that all Excel will house is a pivot table from the Access database.

Could anyone please tell me if there is a good way to do this? I am just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table with 2 columns: user_value (text) and numeric_value (number). Get all of the user entered values uniquely from the user entered data table with a query (the sigma symbol gives you a group by query). Put these in your new table and assign a numerical value to them. Then you can create an output query which joins your data to the lookup table and retrieves the numerical value for each user entered value.